# Converter letra por numero no visualG

Tags: visualg

É possível criar um algoritmo no visualg que leia uma letra e transforme por uma outra letra ou por um numero que já estivesse armazenado no algorítimo? 
Como uma criptografia simples?

A lógica seria :

```
A = B
B = C
C = D
```

Se digitado A, aparecia no final B, e sucessivamente.

O objetivo final seria ler frases inteiras com espaços e trocar por números ou letras.. Mas por ora, quero saber se dá pra fazer no viualG.

Comecei fazendo, mas a sintase está errada.
Ex.:

```
   Escreval("Escreva uma letra de A a D para conversão: ")
     leia(textoc)
     textoc <- textocc
    se textoc = a entao
   escreval("Texto codificado: ")
 escreval("b")
fimse
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `asc` para converter a letra para um número de acordo com a [tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), manipular o número e então usar `carac` para converter de volta para texto.

```
Escreval("Escreva uma letra de A a D para conversão: ")
leia(textoc)
z <- asc(textoc)
z <- z + 1
textocc = carac(z)
escreval("Texto codificado: ")
escreval(textocc)
```